# How to align different part of a text file which contain the distinct delimiters in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, perl

I have a file as follows,

```
b | b | c
aaaaaaaa | b |    c

1,2,3
10000,3,4,
```

I want to align it with both delimiters i.e. `|` and `,`. Expected output file is

```
b        | b | c
aaaaaaaa | b | c

1,     2, 3
10000, 3, 4,
```

Can it be done in using any simple command? Command should not disturb other text in the file (which does not contain that delimiter).

Comment: What if the line contains both delimiters? Are lines with the same delimiter always adjacent?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: "_Can it be done in using any simple command?_"  -- I wouldn't think so, given what need be done---  Either: Read the whole file in, and in the process find the maximum width for each column; then write it out, now knowing how wide each field should be; Or: make one pass over the file to find those maximum widths, then another pass to read a line and write out with right field widths, to a new file that you'll eventually move over the original (advantage of this approach: you never read the _whole_ file in, it's always one line at a time).

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to find the width of each column. Once you have that, you can easily create a `sprintf` format.

```
use List::Util qw( max );

my @a = (
    [qw( b b c )],
    [qw( aaaaaaaa b c )],
);

my @col_widths =
   map {
      my $col_idx = $_;
      max
         map { length($a[$_][$col_idx]) }
            0..$#a
   }
      0..$#{ $a[0] };

# 8, 1, 1 => "%-8s | %-1s | %s"
my $format =
   join " | ",
      map("%-${_}s", @col_widths[ 0..$#col_widths-1 ]),
      "%s";

say sprintf($format, @$_)
   for @a;
```

In the second case, a space for the comma needs to be included in the format width, and a comma needs to be added to each column value except the last.

```
# 5, 1, 1 => "%-6s %-2s %s"
my $format =
   join " ",
      map({ sprintf("%%-%ss", $col_widths[$_]+1) }
         0..$#col_widths-1
      ),
      "%s";

say
   sprintf($format,
      map("$_,", @$_[ 0..$#$_-1 ]),
      $_->[-1],
   )
      for @a;
```

The solutions assume that each row has the same number of columns. Adjust as necessary.